# Where are the Game save files located in PC?

Tags: sd-card, files, bluestacks

I have installed Bluestack on my PC and I began by installing a game called Townsmen and I played nicely. However, I want to backup the files that are created by the Bluestack program since I regularly restore my PC due to it get infected with Adwares and Malwares. I do not want to start the game again from scratch.

I know the default location for the installation is `C:\Program Files\BlueStacks` in Windows XP and some of the settings are stored in `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data`. But I can't find that particular file with the name Townsmen.

Where & how can I access them from the PC?

Answer (score 7):

You can do that manually from the Bluestack app player by doing the following

**1 - Backup the game saves :**

- Download ES File Explorer from the app store/Play Store
- Open ES File Explorer and go to the Root Folder (click on **"/"** in the navigation bar)
- Go to `/data` folder, and then open the folder `/data` inside it (final path: `/data/data`)
- Now you can see a lot of folders name like `com.android.something` or `com.something.somethingelse`. Scroll down and look for a folder named `com.hg.townsmen6`. Long press on it and then click on the three dots (on the bottom right corner of the screen) and choose **Copy to**.

  [image: windows]
  [image: windows]
  [image]
- After clicking **OK**, you will get a toast notification that the copy went successful.
- Now go back to your desktop (Windows desktop) and go to this path `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder`, you will find your folder there. Save it somewhere safe.

**2 - Restore the game's progress after a fresh install do the following :**

- When fresh installing, use this tutorial to get a prerooted Bluestack application [Latest Bluestacks 0.9.14.4604 With SuperUser March 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ex3OIYpNIQ)
- Install the app Townsmen from the app store along with the ES Explorer app (do not open the app Townsmen before finishing the next step.
- Copy back the folder we backed up earlier in the `/data/data` folder
- Now open your game and enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but that works perfectly on the mobile device with root access, which needs to be enabled from the settings in ES File explorer. But i can't do that on BlueStack , even when i install it on Bluestack, when i check the root access it says, "This feature cannot run on this device", because it is PC. So the data folder within the data folder cannot be accessed. Have you tried this on Bluestack ?

Comment: My bad forgot that you will not have root access permissions on a regular blue stacks, updated the answer with a link to the latest rooted bluestacks app player I use titanium backup on mine but I was on a rooted version when I first installed my apps since you have no root access on your current version you can't use titanium that's why I used es explorer method you can read /data with es explorer even if you don't have root ,when you will restore you gonna have root and you will be able to write to /data

Comment: @beta_ubuntu_user first happy that you like my answer ,but you can't post an other question in an answer it's kinda the rules over here and it helps other people to find the answer they looking for without asking questions ,so please post a new question and send me the link I will be more than happy to answer,if the my answer helped you up vote it and if it solved your question accept the question so this question go solved and other people may find it.

Comment: @ Lôrd Ralf Adolf: Actually i wanted to upload a picture and the default comment section doesn't have the feature to do so. I'll keep that in mind, to my next question, if u' r willing to answer, what about some games that comes with obb folder, where do i place that in Bluestack.In the mobile device it would be Storage/Android/obb folder, right, but where do i place those folders in Bluestack.

Comment: not a problem :) ,try puting them on /mnt/storage/sdcard/android/obb/

Answer (score 0):

All Android files (including game saves) are located inside VDI files (VirtualBox drive image) at `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder`. You can try to convert them into image which can be mounted, but on Windows it's easier to install Total Commander app with FTP or SCP plugin, then transfer the game save files via network. Alternatively backup them via the cloud.

See also:

- [How to transfer files between BlueStacks and Windows PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/105503/110425)
- [where is the root folder of bluestacks located in pc?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/149276/110425)