# Where does BlueStacks store my app's data (e.g. save game files)?

Tags: storage, file-management, bluestacks

Where does BlueStacks install my apps and where does it store the data (e.g. saved game files) for those apps?

Answer (score 2):

In Bluestacks 3 and 3N, apps are installed in various Android folders, such as:

- `/data/app` (stores APKs)
- `/data/app-lib` (libraries)
- `/data/data`
- and more.

`/data/data` also contains your app's data (such as save files, whether the app stores game progress locally). **You need to root the emulator to access those folders.**

`Userdata\SharedFolder` only contains files that you shared between Windows and the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 or below:`<BLUESTACKS_DATA>\UserData\SharedFolder` By default, `<BLUESTACKS_DATA>` is `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks`.

So **`C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder`** is where you'd want to look.

Some Windows 10 installations put it here: **`C:\BlueStacks\Engine\UserData\SharedFolder`**

More info here: [How to transfer files between BlueStacks and Windows PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105503/how-to-transfer-files-between-bluestacks-and-windows-pc)

Answer (score 0):

Mine is located on Windows 10 for Bluestacks 4:

C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\Engine\UserData\SharedFolder

Comment: For me, the folder is empty, but exists.