# How to access Local PC drives in Bluestacks

Tags: bluestacks

I have installed BS 4 on my windows 10 laptop.
Now i have installed ES File Explorer on it through Google Play Store.
After that when i am trying to access my local drives i am unable to access it or you can say unable to find path of local drives.

[image]

[image]

Secondly, i observe my windows icon has QUESTION MARK why it is like that.

Thanks
Adeel Imtiaz

Comment: This may help [How to transfer files between BlueStacks and Windows PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/105503)

Answer (score 4):

You can easily share files between BlueStacks and Windows using shared folders. Just place your file inside it and you can access it from both Windows and BlueStacks.

Let's understand it:

The default shared folder in Windows is located in **C:\ ProgramData\ BlueStacks\ UserData\ SharedFolder**  *(assuming C:\ is your Windows installation drive).* In BlueStacks, the same folder is located in **(Root)/ sdcard/ bstfolder/ BstSharedFolder.**

> BstsharedFolder is bluestacks shared folder with your pc contents and vice versa.
>
> You have to put files into the above folder to make accessible from pc as well as from bluestacks itself.

Additionally, the default Windows Library folders are accessible from BlueStacks. They are located in **/sdcard/bstfolder/** as Pictures, Documents, etc.

A file manager app is required to navigate folders inside BlueStacks. In this answer, i'm  using OI File Manager. To share a file, follow the steps below:

> 1.Download and install [OI File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.openintents.filemanager) in BlueStacks.
>
> 2.On Windows, navigate to BlueStacks Shared Folder **[C:\ ProgramData\ BlueStacks\ UserData\ SharedFolder]** and place the files you want to use in BlueStacks (like photos, videos, downloaded APK files, etc.). You can also use the Windows Library Folders for this purpose.
>
> 3.In BlueStacks, launch OI File Manager and navigate to BlueStacks shared folder **[(Root)/ sdcard/ bstfolder/ BstSharedFolder].** If you have placed files in your Windows Library, locate the respective folder from bstfolder directory in BlueStacks.

Similarly if you want to access BlueStacks files from your computer, copy the particular file to BstSharedFolder using OI File Manager and the same file will be available in Windows SharedFolder location.

Note: This article is originally written by David. [Source](https://7labs.io/tips-tricks/how-to-access-your-computers-files-in-bluestacks-on-windows.html)