# Where is the root folder of BlueStacks located in PC?

Tags: bluestacks

Is there a way to locate the files in PC as shown in the root explorer of BlueStacks?

I.e. how to move files of BlueStacks (APKs or any other file) to PC or from PC without opening BlueStacks?

Like, moving files of BlueStacks or computer through the PC directories without involving the use of a shared folder or root explorer or `adb` shell
a simpler way?

Answer (score 6):

BlueStacks is an Android emulator, which is basically running virtual machine with different operating system, therefore you can't access your files directly.

You can find your data files under: `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder` on Windows or `Library/BlueStacks/Android` on Mac, but the data files are in 'VDI' format (VirtualBox Drive Image).

So you can try to convert .vdi files into RAW image which you can mount by the following command:

```
VBoxManage clonehd --format RAW Root.vdi Root.img
```

Then you can try to mount these files by some software which can support Linux ext3 file systems.

---

Alternatively you can install *Total Commander*, *Root* or *File Explorer* (or similar app) in BlueStacks, then transfer your files into fake SSD card and they should appear in `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder` folder. On Mac, you probably need to convert `SDCard.vdi` file into RAW format (as mentioned above) and mount the image, or use VirtualBox software to access the VDI image.

---

Another easier way is simply to install FTP or SCP plugin for *Total Commander* app and transfer the files via network.

Comment: From Bluestacks v4 there's "Media manager" app installed in the Bluestack Android. With the help of this app it is easy to import/export any files between Bluestacks and host OS. https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360021374972-Introducing-the-Media-Manager-on-BlueStacks-4

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps on this Xda developer page to get to the root directory of bluestacks: [Find Bluestacks SD Card Location in Your PC](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2292232). Here are the steps:

> - First Download 'Root Explorer' (Included Below) and Install 'Root Explorer' in Bluestacks
> - Decide on which directory to give access in BlueStacks. You can either choose an entire hard drive, or a particular folder of your
>     choice.
> - Access the Windows Registry by going to Start >> Run and type in 'regedit' and hit Enter. This opens up the Registry Editor.
> - Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\SharedFolder\0`.
> - Right Click on 'Path' and click on 'Modify'.
> - Write the path of the folder which you want to include in SD card. (Example `C:\SDCard`)
> - Restart your computer for the changes to take effect.
> - You can find the folder at '(Root)/sdcard/bstfolder/ BstSharedFolder/'
>
> If u don't wanna change your Registry, You can simply copy and paste the file's that you want in SD Card at 'C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\UserData\SharedFolder\' and find the files at above location in Root Explorer (ie '(Root)/sdcard/bstfolder/ BstSharedFolder/').

---

Also if that isn't what you are looking for here is another link to get to the actual folder which apps are stored: [Access your local files from BlueStacks on Windows](https://7labs.heypub.com/tips-tricks/how-to-access-your-computers-files-in-bluestacks-on-windows.html). Here are the different methods:

> - Using Bluestacks Shared folder
>
> > - Download and install OI File Manager in BlueStacks.
> > - On Windows, navigate to BlueStacks Shared Folder [C:\ ProgramData\ BlueStacks\ UserData\ SharedFolder] and place the files you want to
> >       use in BlueStacks (like photos, videos, downloaded APK files, etc.).
> >       You can also use the Windows Library Folders for this purpose.
> > - In BlueStacks, launch *OI File Manager* and navigate to BlueStacks shared folder [(Root)/ sdcard/ bstfolder/ BstSharedFolder]. If you
> >       have placed files in your Windows Library, locate the respective
> >       folder from bstfolder directory in BlueStacks.
> > - Similarly if you want to access BlueStacks files from your computer, copy the particular file to BstSharedFolder using OI File Manager and
> >       the same file will be available in Windows SharedFolder location.
>
> - Using Drag and Drop (for copy the files in BlueStacks).
>
> > - When BlueStacks is fully ready and running, just drag the particular file from its Windows folder into the BlueStacks interface.
>
> - Using Cloud Sync
> - Using Windows Registry

For further details, follow above link.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can just go to Android settings in BlueStacks and under BlueStacks Settings, you'll find an option "Import files from Windows". Select it and find your file and import it.

Comment: Where is this setting?  I have Bluestacks 4 and I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

BlueStacks also has a Media Manager available in its System Tools app in the emulator.

See https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034476511-Introducing-the-Media-Manager-on-BlueStacks-4 or https://support.bluestacks.com/hc/en-us/articles/360055684992-Media-Manager-on-BlueStacks-5